# Rails data modelling with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am building an expense tracker application and I am in middle of data modelling. I have a Users table. Each user will log his expenses with expense type and income with income type. So I need to know how can we set up associations for it.

I have User, Expense, Income and UserTransaction models.

Expense and Income will have following fields

> id, date, category, amount, description, user_id, currency

I am not sure whether I need UserTransaction table also.
But my business requirement is as follows

I should be able to get all expenses/income of a user with date range and also with category

I should also be able to get all transactions occurred with date range.

Comment: I guess the has_many through is not required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to maintain both income and expenses in the same table. If you are thinking the same you need to use polymorphic association.

Polymorphic association is best explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

let me know, if you still have clarifications